# Modeling Stakeholder relationships in ontologies

Tags: ontology

First: I hope I am in the correct place of StackExchange to ask Ontology related questions.

I want to model relationships between agents and projects. There fore i have `objectProperties` of the kind: `isStakeholderAgentProject`, where i have sub properties representing the actual stakholder type (e.g. `isManagerAgentProject`).

Additionally I have `SystemRightsStatements` (sub class of `dc/terms/RightsStatement`).

How can I associate `RightsStatements` to object `Properties`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. The answer was fairly simple.

What I was looking for was N-ary relations. 
How this can be achived is documented by the W3C: ["Defining N-ary Relations on the Semantic Web"](https://www.w3.org/TR/swbp-n-aryRelations/)